# Remote access to MySQL DB hosted in OpenShift (not looking for the port forwarding solution)

Tags: python, mysql, django, openshift, paas

I spent the whole yesterday migrating my `django` application to `OpenShift` (I selected the free solution and my application is using one small gear). My application is now up and running and there are no issues visiting the site using a browser.

However I have a `.NET (C#) application` which accompanies the web application and it will be run by many different users and it needs to access the database but I can not find a way to do this in OpenShift.

All the different IP addresses seems to be local and I can not find a way to access the MySQL database remotely. Below are the environment variables from OpenShift:

```
env | grep MYSQL
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/.../mysql/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=3306
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.13.169.130
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=...
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_IDENT=redhat:mysql:5.5:0.2.9
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=...
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET=/var/lib/openshift/.../mysql//socket/mysql.sock
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://..-...@127.13.169.130:3306/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_LOG_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/.../mysql//log/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64
```

As explained in the title I am not looking for the port forwarding solution. (I need to make it work not only for me but all the users)

- What am I missing?
- Why can't databases be accessed externally?
- What should I do?
- Are there any other FREE paas out there which offer what I am looking for?
- Do I need to get a medium or big gear in order for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, lots of googleing and I now know that using the free solution provided by `OpenShift` it is **not possible** to solve this issue.
You must upgrade to a paid version in order to get another port to access the sql database directly.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Having a paid account would still not allow you to access your database directly without using port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use port forwarding, then I would suggest you write an API that your .NET application can use to access the database.  Otherwise you would want to look into an externally hosted database (DBaaS) solution.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate some more?